# String containing Another String value

Tags: ms-access, vba

Is there any possibilities to ask such a thing :

```
If me.cbo.Column(0) = "certain value containing let's say "ABC"" Then
```

So if there's 123ABC or ABC123 or even 123ABC123, then it will be valid ?

Comment: No, it won't since you require equal values.  123ABC does not equal ABC.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `= "ABC"` use `Like "*ABC*"`

```
If me.cbo.Column(0) Like "*ABC*" Then
```

The *'s act like wildcards.

Another option would be like this:

```
If Instr(me.cbo.Column(0), "ABC") > 0 Then
```

Comment: If me.cbo.Column(0) = "*ABC*" Then

Like this ?